# Generalized diagonalization with Lapack

Tags: fortran, lapack

I am having some problems using the subroutine DSYGV of Lapack:

```
DSYGV( ITYPE, JOBZ, UPLO, N, A, LDA, B, LDB, W, WORK,LWORK, INFO )
```

This is the diagonalization I want to carry out:

```
v_mat*x = eig*t_mat*x
```

This is the crucial piece of my code:

```
program pruebadiago

real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: v_mat, t_mat

real, dimension(:), allocatable   :: eig,WORK

real , parameter                  :: k=3.0,m=4.0

integer, parameter                :: n=2

integer                           :: i

! EXPECTED EIGENVALUES AND EIGENVECTORS

!eig = 0.286475  ------>  u = (0.262866 , 0.425325)

!eig = 1.96353   ------>  u = (0.425325, -0.262866)

allocate(v_mat(n,n),t_mat(n,n),eig(n))

!--------------------------

v_mat(1,1:2) = (/2.0*k,-k/)

v_mat(2,1:2) = (/-k,k/)

!--------------------------

!--------------------------

t_mat(1,1:2) = (/m,0.0/)

t_mat(2,1:2) = (/0.0,m/)

!---------------------------

!diagonalizacion

call DSYGV( 1, 'v', 'u', n , v_mat, 2 , t_mat, 2, eig, WORK,-1, INF )

LWORK=WORK(1)

allocate(WORK(LWORK))

call  DSYGV( 1, 'v', 'u', n , v_mat, 2 , t_mat, 2, eig, WORK,LWORK, INF )

open(unit=100,file="pruebadiago.dat",status="replace",action="write")

do i = 1,n

write(unit=100,fmt=*) "E",i,"=",eig(i),(v_mat(i,j),j=1,n)

!autofuntzioak zutabeka doaz"(100f12.6)"

enddo

close(unit=100)

deallocate(v_mat,t_mat,eig,WORK)

end program pruebadiago
```

I think I understood everything given in this document:

```
http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.1.1/html/dsygv.f.html
```

But the argument LWORK which I did not understand so I just try different values.

I know something is wrong because I know what are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix and I get wrong eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and I am doing such a simple calculation in order to understand the way it works and then compute huge diagonalizations.

Does anybody see what is the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are missing some elements from the code you posted. Basically the array declarations of WORK,eig,v_mat and t_mat.

Anyway, LWORK argument actually is the size of WORK vector. i.e

```
DOUBLE PRECISION WORK(100)
LWORK=100
```

Lapack specifies as minimum value of `LWORK=3*N-1`. In your case `N=2`.

For this example case I would suggested to use a big WORK vector (i.e. 100) so that you will not encounter any problems from that.

For large matrices you should use double call of `DSYGV`.

- First call with `LWORK=-1` and get suggested size from `WORK(1)`
- Allocate a `NEW WORK` vector with suggested size.
- Finally solve eigenproblem with `DSYGV`.

Sample code is:

```
CALL DSYGV( 1, 'V', 'U', 2 , v_mat, 2 , t_mat, 2, eig, W, -1, INF )
LWORK=W(1)
ALLOCATE ( WORK(LWORK) )
CALL DSYGV( 1, 'V', 'U', 2 , v_mat, 2 , t_mat, 2, eig, WORK, LWORK, INF )
```

Additionally, you need to check `INF` value after `DSYGV` call. If it is not zero then an error occurred.

***EDIT**: Fixed source code*

```
program pruebadiago

double precision, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: v_mat, t_mat
double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: eig,WORK
double precision :: W
double precision , parameter :: k=3.0,m=4.0
integer, parameter :: n=2
integer :: i

! EXPECTED EIGENVALUES AND EIGENVECTORS
!eig = 0.286475 ------> u = (0.262866 , 0.425325)
!eig = 1.96353 ------> u = (0.425325, -0.262866)

allocate(v_mat(n,n),t_mat(n,n),eig(n))

!--------------------------
v_mat(1,1:2) = (/2.0*k,-k/)
v_mat(2,1:2) = (/-k,k/)
!--------------------------
t_mat(1,1:2) = (/m,0.0d0/)
t_mat(2,1:2) = (/0.0d0,m/)
!---------------------------

call DSYGV( 1, 'v', 'u', n , v_mat, 2 , t_mat, 2, eig, W,-1, INF )

LWORK=W
allocate(WORK(LWORK))

call DSYGV( 1, 'v', 'u', n , v_mat, 2 , t_mat, 2, eig, WORK,LWORK, INF )
open(unit=100,file="pruebadiago.dat",status="replace",action="write")
do i = 1,n
  write(unit=100,fmt=*) "E",i,"=",eig(i),(v_mat(i,j),j=1,n)
enddo

close(unit=100)
deallocate(v_mat,t_mat,eig,WORK)

end program pruebadiago
```

Comment: The attached document says: (workspace/output) DOUBLE PRECISION array, dimension (MAX(1,LWORK))
On exit, if INFO = 0, WORK(1) returns the optimal LWORK.

Comment: The work vector is memory space needed by `DSYGV` during the computations. It saves intermediate vectors in it. The minimum size for successful execution is `3*N-1`. The optimal size for speed is `(NB+2)*N`. The `NB` is computed internally be LAPACK and it is basically unknown. This is the reason we need to call `DSYGV` twice.

Comment: So, should it have the same size as  V_mat or t_mat? Or what size should it have?

Comment: A safe choice would be to use always `3*N`. In most cases this is smaller than A,B matrices.

Comment: I noticed two things in your source code. First you define matrices as real (4byte) and use `DSYGV` (double: 8byte). You should convert all real definitions to double precision.
Second you should not use WORK array before allocating it. Instead you can use a simple W value in first call of `DSYGV`:
`double precision :: W`,
`call DSYGV( 1, 'v', 'u', n , v_mat, 2 , t_mat, 2, eig, W,-1, INF )`
,`LWORK=W`

Comment: thanks so much!!!! You seem to know a lot about fortran, could we go to the chat for 5 mins? I would like to ask you something very specific, but it has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37480/discussion-between-ctheo-and-mencia)